# Destroy link is looking for show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having an issue with my Rails app; specifically my 'destroy' link is taking me to the show page. Destroy was working a few hours ago (I tried it) but have obviously messed something up since then. I'm a relative beginner at Rails and have looked through documentation and also this site to try and figure out how to fix the issue myself with no success. Others have had similar issues, I've applied the fixes that worked for them but that hasn't fixed the issue either. Hopefully someone more advanced than me can spot the issue! I'm using Rails v3.2.8.

In index.html.erb, I have:

`<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', school, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>`

In schools_controller.rb, I have:

```
def destroy
 @school = School.find(params[:id])
 @school.destroy

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to schools_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end
```

This is what I'm seeing in the Rails server:

```
Started GET "/schools/7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-27 16:02:55 +0000
Processing by SchoolsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}
  School Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schools".* FROM "schools" WHERE "schools"."id" = ? LIMIT
1  [["id", "7"]]
  Rendered schools/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 17.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-27 16:02:5
6 +0000
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-27 16:02:56
 +0000
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

My application.html.erb has:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Application.js has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks, Catherine

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors on the page that has the delete link on it? If so, fix them - they will stop the JavaScript that makes the request a DELETE request, from working.

Comment: No, I didn't see any errors.

Answer (score 0):

In index.html.erb, I changed link_to to button_to and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

please crosscheck your given on link it should be like that:

```
 <%= link_to "REMOVE", remove_path , method: :delete %>
```